# Javascript Check If One Date Is 7 Days Ahead Of Another Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a date comparison for our application. The goal is take the *Start Date* the user inputs, and check it against the *Operator/Region Effective Date* which acts as the date a new list of product prices can be used. We want to see if there is an *Effective Date* 7 days in the future on the *Start Date*. If so, we want to display a message and let them know the prices are changing soon.

I figure the best thing to do is add 7 days to the *Start Date* and then see if its less then or equal to the *Effective Date*, if so, that would mean it is within the range. I just dont know how to add 7 days  to the *Start Date*. Everything I have tried is giving me an "Invalid Date" back. Any ideas?

**Code I've Tried So Far**

```
    public checkStartDates = () => {
    const checkDates = this.state.checkDate;
    const region = this.state.well.region;

    const d1 = new Date(checkDates.startDate + 7);

    const d2 = new Date(region.effectiveDate);

    console.log(d1, d2);
    if (d1 > d2) {
        alert ("Error!");
    }
}

    public checkStartDates = () => {
    const checkDates = this.state.checkDate;
    const region = this.state.well.region;

    const d1 = new Date(checkDates.startDate + 7);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 7);

    const d2 = new Date(region.effectiveDate);

    console.log(d1, d2);
    if (d1 > d2) {
        alert ("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add days to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date) `const d1 = new Date(checkDates.startDate); d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 7);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is `startDate` probably is not a number. So you are trying to add a number on onto something else which really isn't one. You already had it with the `d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 7);` line. You don't need the `+ 7` on the date init.

Try this:

```
    const d1 = new Date(checkDates.startDate)
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 7);

    const d2 = new Date(region.effectiveDate);

    console.log(d1, d2);
    if (d1 > d2) {
        alert ("Error!");
    }
```